# Calendar view with items pointing to page url

Tags: 2010, calendar, pages

(I'm using SharePoint 2010)

I have a Pages library on which I attached a custom "AnEvent" content type who inherits from the Article Page content type.  The "AnEvent" content type contains a start date and an end date.  I created a Calendar view on the Page Library and I display that view on the home page of my site.

When I click on an item in the calendar, the display form of the item is displayed.  Instead I would like to click on the title of the item and be taken to the actual page of the item.  I can't seem to be able to display the Title on the event with a link to the page of the event.

Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I am also trying to find the solution to this; surely it's possible? I'm coming from a Drupal background so in my mind this isn't hard but with no previous SharePoint / .net knowledge it's looking impossible.